# Flash AS3 Tower Defense MouseEvents

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, optimization, events, tower-defense

In my tower defense game and every tile has its own mouse event listener. I am wondering, would it be better to use one event listener (MouseEvent.CLICK) and then when it runs the function, should I just use evt.target to determine what was clicked, and then run an appropriate function?

I am programming the game for web and phone and I started to notice some lag on my phone so I am trying to optimize my code. Any other tips to speed up code would help too.

Comment: I don't have any experience with flash on mobile devices, but I find it hard to believe that it's connected to event-listeners. In what situations does your game lag?

Comment: The enemies on the path just stop or move slow. I wanted to start optimizing the code. Mouse Events are one of the first things I thought of.

Another thing that might be slowing down my game is the sorting of the enemies. When a wave appears, the enemies in the wave are put into an array. I have enemies that are faster than others so they will pass enemies on the path. I want my towers to shoot whichever enemy is in front. To do this, each time my game updates, I find the distance traveled and sort the enemies with a bubble sort depending on which one moved the furthest.

Comment: Hm tricky. If you can somehow manage to remove the event-listeners (by pre-populating the board, so that you won't need mouse events), that would probably be the easiest way to check if the events are actually the bottleneck here.

Comment: I will try that. I was just wondering if one event listener for everything would still be better than creating an event listener for each individual object.

Comment: Sure, one event listener would also work. You could use the `target` property then. But not even that is required, since you could determine the clicked tile by calculating the index by using the mouse coordinates given by the event. That would allow you to use some light-weight components like `Shape` for your tiles, or draw the tiles directly to a bitmap.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I doubt that the event listeners are the main bottleneck of your applications. However as you are trying to optimize your code, here are some useful informations to know about Events alternatives and performances.

The main alternatives to the Events are the Signals & Slots, Observers and indeed the direct Callbacks.

*Performance tests and articles:*

- [Callback Strategies](http://jacksondunstan.com/articles/573)
- [TurboSignal vs As3Signal vs Events](http://jacksondunstan.com/articles/585) (also an introduction to TubroEvent. Tests at the bottom)
- [Events vs AS3signal](http://alecmce.com/as3/events-and-signals-performance-tests)
- [Events vs AS3signal vs Callbacks](http://va.lent.in/blog/2010/01/27/omg-as3-signals-are-faster-than-events1)
- [Another Event vs AS3signal](http://www.rossgerbasi.com/2010/09/as3signals-vs-events/)
- [Runnables (Observers)](http://jacksondunstan.com/articles/323)

*AS3 Signal libraries:*

- [Robert Penner’s as3signals](https://github.com/robertpenner/as3-signals/wiki/)
- [Jackson Dunstan's TubroSignal](http://jacksondunstan.com/turbosignals)
- probably others I don't know of...

---

Finally, you can check this [video tutorial about how to use as3signal](http://johnlindquist.com/2010/01/21/as3-signals-tutorial/)

Comment: I have been looking at signals. I want to start using those to take some of the stress off my update function.

Comment: I think another thing that could help would be to use less movieclips and more sprites or just bitmap data. My problem is, I don't know how to add bitmaps to a sprite or to bitmap objects and then display them.

Comment: MovieClip inherit from the Sprite class. So a MovieClip is a Sprite with some special methods and properties mainly focused on the timeline concept. You should use MovieClips when you need to manipulate their 'timeline' (frames) else you'd better use the Sprites.
(Beside this, you should consider to choose some 'accepted' answers on your previous questions. You didn't accepted any of them, and accepting the answers that helped you will make people more prone to answer new questions. Not this one however, it's still early and you can have other answers.)

Comment: @Valkea, sorry about not selecting answers. I am still learning how everything on this site works. I selected the answers to my other questions.

Comment: No problem, it's just better if you want more answers ;).

Comment: I started using signals and it does seem to help performance a bit. Now, I am just wondering how many I should use. Right now in my game loop, it checks every frame whether an enemy died or reached the end. Would it be better to leave it like that or should I fire a signal when an enemy died to tell the main class that it happened? If I do this, I will have a signal and listener for every single enemy created. Is that better than just checking every frame?

Comment: In this context, signals should do a better job than checking all enemies state. But no you doesn't need to get a signal and a listener(slot) for every single enemy created, you should have ONE **slot** on the class that deal with enemies life, deaths etc. and 1 **signal** on each enemies. When the enemies dies, or change life etc. it does ".dispatch()" to the registered slot its new state. This is the slot stuff to act correctly using the informations provided by the signal received to know "Who" died etc. The signal will call for the slot (listener) only when the dispatch function is called.

Comment: I don't completely understand. Right now, when enemies are created, a signal fires and sends the enemy instance to the main class. The main class then adds the enemy to an array of all enemies. In the enemy class, I will create a signal that dispatches if the enemy dies. However, in the main class, wouldn't I need to loop through each enemy instance and add a listener? The listener would go to the same function, but wouldn't I still need one for every enemy instance?

Comment: By the way, I have just been using Robert Penner's as3signals. I haven't really looked into turbosignals or anything else.

Comment: Yes you need to register each signal to the main slot, but only once. After that, each dispatch call will be handled normally when required (not at each frame), thus you don't have to loop over all the registered enemies. You should take a loot at the 'Usage Example (complex)' in the TurboSignal introduction (linked in my answer), it does fit what you need from what I understand. You should also consider the pertinence of using signals instead of direct function calls... it's up to you the choose the better depending of your current situation.

Comment: I just found this video: [Responding to Game Events in the Citrus Engine](http://vimeo.com/10105904). "This tutorial shows you how to listen for events in your game and respond to them accordingly". I do not have the time to look at it right now, but considering the title and the introduction sentence it could be useful to you (well using signals or whatever you need instead of normal events).

Comment: I haven't looked at your video yet since I am at work, but looking at the 'Usage Example (complex)' in your previous post, it looks like there is a slot for each button. Using just as3signals, I was thinking I would have in the enemy class: `public var EnemyDied:Signal` which will dispatch whenever the enemy dies. In my main class, whenever an enemy is created, I will have `enemyInstance.EnemyDied.add(EnemyDiedHandler)`. So what I meant earlier, is that I would have a signal and a listener for each enemy. Is there a way so I could have one signal that listens for any EnemyDied dispatch?

Comment: Hum in the 'Usage Example (complex)' I see a signals on each button (`public var clicked:Signal1 = new Signal1();`) that is dispatched (`clicked.dispatch(this);`) and one slot on the MainMenu (`public class MainMenu implements Slot1`) which register for all the button signals (`button1.clicked.addSlot(this);`). So this is exactly what you are describing with your enemy class.

Comment: To answer your last question, no you can't register "all" enemies at once, you have to register each instance one by one. But you can delegate this job to the Enemy class by providing it the reference to the main slot and registering it to the slot in the constructor method (`this.addSlot(theMainSlot);`). This way each time a new Enemy class instance is created, it will auto register its signal to the main slot, and each time it is destroyed it will unregister the signal from the slot.